# Python, handling session in CGI

Tags: python, cgi

I am doing a simple project, and I want to have a login session. There is a good example here: http://webpython.codepoint.net/cgi_session_class but I can not understand, how do I check if the session is already established?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That class takes care of handling new sessions entirely transparently.

The only way you can detect if a session is new is by storing something in the session and test for that:

```
if not 'seen' in session.data:
    # new session, set a flag
    session.data['seen'] = True
```

because a new session is always empty, but only if you set values will returning sessions *not* be empty.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I guessed. Do you know, why do I get "message = "'Session' object has no attribute 'data'"" error?

Comment: @Anarion: you need to create an *instance* of the `Session` class, only instances have the `data` attribute: `session = Session(...)`.

Comment: That's how I'm using it: `sess = session.Session(expires=365*24*60*60, cookie_path='/')` and I get an eroor inside of the class, on thins line: `elif isinstance(expires, int):
=>   51                         self.data['cookie']['expires'] = expires`

Comment: MAy be this line didn't work? 
`self.data = shelve.open(session_dir + '/sess_' + sid, writeback=True)`

Comment: Every time I create a session object - it is a new session, how do I keep the session alive between different pages?

Comment: Are you sending the `Set-Cookie` header at all? Do read and understand the sample code in that page first.

Comment: I read the code, but I am not sure I understood everything from there. I thought the Session class handles sending the cookie by itself, without me needing to do anything.

Comment: Ah, so I needed to `print sess.cookie` in order to send the cookie.... Now, how do I "logg off" ?

Comment: No, with CGI you need to handle all headers yourself. Logging off would mean you set a cookie with an Expires header set to the past so the browser clears the cookie from its storage.